# AlarmManager not taking more than one queue Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I just recently started to mess with the alarm manager, and I figured out most of it, but right now its starting to be a bit annoying. So, right now I have it set up with a date and time picker, you type in the date and time and it will pop up a toast message when that times comes, but it seems like it will only take one alarm and any other ones I set get destroyed. Is this something the alarm manager does by itself, or is there something I am missing. Here is my code for my main class, the other is just a broadcast receiver with a toast message in it, so I won't post it.

```
public class TextScheduler extends ListActivity {
protected Toast mToast; 
TimePicker time;
DatePicker date;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(setTime);
    time = (TimePicker) this.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    date = (DatePicker) this.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
}
private OnClickListener setTime = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth(), time.getCurrentHour(), time.getCurrentMinute());

        Intent intent = new Intent(TextScheduler.this, AReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("caldata", "hooray!!");
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TextScheduler.this, 1234567, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
    }
};
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more info, thanks in advance!

WWaldo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlarmManager compares PendingIntents to see if it already exits. Just change the ID (in your case `1234567`), and it will allow you to create additional alarms: one per ID.